# Linear Algebra - Economic Models

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, economics

Suppose the coal and steel industries form an open economy. Every \$1 produced by the coal industry requires \$0.15 of coal and \$0.20 of steel. Every \$1 produced by steel requires \$0.25 of coal and \$0.10 of steel. Suppose that there is an annual outside demand for \$45 million of coal and $124 million of steel. (a) How much should each industry produce to satisfy the demands?

In my attempt, I chose x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub> represent the amount of output of coal and steel, respectively. Also, external demand + internal demand = what’s being produced, so:

45 + 0.15x<sub>1</sub> + 0.20x<sub>2</sub> = x<sub>1</sub>

124 + 0.25x<sub>1</sub> + 0.10<sub>2</sub> = x<sub>2</sub>

Rearranging gives

0.85x<sub>1</sub> - 0.20x<sub>2</sub> = 45

-0.25x<sub>1</sub> + 0.90x<sub>2</sub> = 124

Solving this system gives x<sub>1</sub> = 91.3286. . . and x<sub>2</sub> = 163.1485. . .

However, I looked at the answer key of the textbook, and it says coal should produce 100 million (x<sub>1</sub> = 100) and steel should produce 160 million (x<sub>2</sub> = 160). These are suspiciously close to the values I got, but my answers are still wrong.

Is there something wrong with the equations I came up with? I even plugged in my answers to a calculator to check.

Comment: Without seeing your work, we can't possibly try to see what you did wrong. Can you include your attempt in your post?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Ok, thanks for letting me know. I updated it with some more steps. Still, after making the equations, I’m sure I didn’t make a mistake because I checked with an online calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two equations, one for coal and one for steel.

$\textrm{"Every \$1 produced by steel requires \$0.25 of }  \color{red}{\textrm{coal}}"$

This condition has to be in the coal constraint. On the other hand the condition

$\textrm{"Every \$1 produced by the coal industry requires ...  \$0.20 of} \color{blue}{\textrm{ steel}}"$

is for the steel constraint:

\begin{align}
&  x=0.15x+0.25y+45 \quad \color{grey}{\textrm{coal}} \\ &   y=0.20x+0.10y+124 \quad \color{grey}{\textrm{steel}}\\ 
\end{align}

Rearranging the terms gives

\begin{align}
& \ \ \ \  0.85x-0.25y=45 \\ &   -0.20x+0.9y=124 \Rightarrow x=4.5y-620 \\ 
\end{align}

Insterting the value for x into the first constraint:

\begin{align}
& \ \ \ \  0.85\cdot (4.5y-620)-0.25y=45  \\& \\& (0.85\cdot 45-0.25)y=45+0.85\cdot 620 \\& \\& y= \frac{0.85\cdot 620+45}{0.85\cdot 4.5-0.25}=160 \quad \color{grey}{\textrm{steel}}
\end{align}